# How to remove extra rows in tablesorter.js?

Tags: jquery, html, tablesorter

> I am using `tablesorter.js` to sort my html table. My table is
>   nested.Onclick on first row its child row will be open. for this i am
>   using ajax call. on ajax page i have child rows of parent rows.  Now
>   problem is i am having below code on my parent page:

```
 <table class="sortable">
    <thead>            
        <tr class="row">
            <th class="list_gradient"> Organization Name</th>
            <th class="list_gradient"> Vat No</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>   
    <tr class="row">
        <td align="center">
            <a href="#&test=<?php echo  $CUSTOMER_ID?>">
            <img src="include/images/plus.png" onClick="toggleImg(this);toggleDiv('<?php echo $CUSTOMER_ID ?>');displayDetails('<?php echo $CUSTOMER_ID ?>');"/><b></b></a>
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $CUSTOMER_ID;?>" id="reqdId<?php echo $CUSTOMER_ID ?>"/>                             
            <?php echo $org_name?>
        </td>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="11">
                <div class="hidden_rows" id="<?php echo $CUSTOMER_ID ?>" style="display:none; width:100%;"> 
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>              
    </tr>
</table>
```

Above is my table that is working fine without `tablesorter`. If i used to click on header of table it gets sorted but it shows me extra rows too that is i am having for my child rows.

```
        <td colspan="11">
            <div class="hidden_rows" id="<?php echo $CUSTOMER_ID ?>" style="display:none; width:100%;"> 
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

If i remove above code from table then only tablesorter doesn't show my extra lines. But thing is i cant remove above code. i have to hide this rows onclick of sort class. I tried with `hide()` method but it didnt work for me.

Below is my code for hide extra rows in table.

```
$(function(){

    $("table").tablesorter();
    $(".sortable").click(function(){
       $("hidden_rows").hide(); 
    });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML is invalid. You can't nest a `tr` inside another `tr`. Instead move the `<td colspan="11">` into a nested table:

```
<tr class="row">
  <td align="center">...</td>
  <td>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="11">...</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Please set up a demo of the problem using [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/bbxxomhx/). It looks like the user needs to click on the table to toggle the view of nested tables, it would be better to add a button or show the header of the nested table in the cell.